# How to remap `m` key correctly?

Tags: neovim

I want to remap the m key for executing a function after a mark is set. I tried with this function but it doesn't work. The mark function is not running correctly, and `hello world` is never printed. How can I map this correctly? I am not sure how can I wait for `m` to complete its action before running other action.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "m", "m<cmd>echo 'hello world'<cr>", {noremap = true})
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`:h getchar()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29) to let the user input the name of the mark they want to set, otherwise your mapped `m` command will be executed without a mark name and that doesn't work.

Here is an example in vimscript using a function: You remap `m` to call the `MarkAndDo` function. This function reads the input of the user with `getchar()` and uses `execute` to run the command `m + mark name` then you can do whatever you want in the function.

```
function! MarkAndDo()
    execute "normal! m" . nr2char(getchar())
    echo "hello world"
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> m :call MarkAndDo()<CR>
```

Adapting this solution to the `nvim_set_keymap()` api is straight forwards:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "m", ":call MarkAndDo()<CR>", {noremap= true})
```

If you want to keep it a one liner that should be possible too but I think that it's better to use a function to keep your code readable.